# Align icon to be right beside the header

Tags: css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am currently trying to place an icon to be beside the header. However, I tried but it kept not being aligned. May I know why?

Here's the code I've tried

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-1">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-8">
        <div class="row">
            <h2 id="ContentPlaceHolder1_courseDetail" class="col-lg-11">Course Details</h2>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign "></span>
         </div>
         <h5 id="lblLastModifiedDate" class="col-lg-12">Last Modified Date: 21/10/2016 3:02:35 PM</h5>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The span is allowed to be inside your h2 tag, so that it displays next to the text

```
<h2 id="ContentPlaceHolder1_courseDetail" class="col-lg-11">Course Details <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign "></span></h2>
```

Also if you don't actually want them attached as such, you have already set yourself up to display them side by side in other ways

```
<h2 id="ContentPlaceHolder1_courseDetail" class="col-lg-11">Course Details</h2>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign col-md-1"></span>
```

Though that's not advised because the first option is much nicer looking as the latter choice will give a gap between them due to bootstrap's column system

If you do not wish for them to display next to each other, you can also do things like this

```
    <h2 class="col-lg-11"><span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_courseDetail">Course Details</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign col-md-1"></span></h2>
```

Comment: Yeah, I dont actually want them to be attached because I am changing the `innerText` of `h2` when i click the icon.. I tried my way but it doesn't align horizontally, neither are they side by side

Comment: Oops have another look at the second option, I messed up and didn't indent it so it thought it was real html haha